# Phantom Center Y constraint being added to view on runtime

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to position an image view inside a nib using autolayout:

[image]

Here are the constraints of the image view:

[image]

However, on runtime, my height constraint is breaking due to a conflict with a center Y constraint with the parent view (`TUFailedSharingView`). The problem is: I'm not creating any center Y constraint anywhere!

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009b530 UIImageView:0x10193a180.height == 31>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170280460 TUFailedSharingView:0x10190d940.height == 65>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170280640 UIImageView:0x10193a180.top == TUFailedSharingView:0x10190d940.top + 16.5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170281680 UIImageView:0x10193a180.centerY == TUFailedSharingView:0x10190d940.centerY>"
)
```

The image view height constraint is okay (due to 1:1 aspect ratio), parent height constraint is also okay (I've set it up), the top constraint is also okay, but where does the center Y constraint even come from? I'm not adding it anywhere (neither in code or IB). How can iOS create a "phantom" center Y constraint?

Comment: If your label doesn't have a constraint to the top **and** bottom of the superview then you need your image view to have a constraint to the top **and** bottom of the containing view; otherwise the system can't work out how tall `TUFailedSharingView` should be

Comment: @Paulw11 this applies if I haven't specified a height for the failed sharing view explicity, which in this case I do have it. I have the top constraint and width/aspect ratio (which would calculate height) constraint which are enough for y position and height of the image view, and I have height constraint (65) on the parent (failed sharing view) itself which is enough for it to calculate its height.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I could not find source TUFailedSharingView. I suspect this view might be doing this.

Comment: @BangOperator that's my custom view class :) doesn't have anything fancy about layout. it's just a subclass of UIView without any custom layout code.